# Magento 2 override css of specific tag

Tags: magento-2.1, css

I want to override the css for  tag globally, it is not enclosed so I want to apply word-wrap property on it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to presume you're using the default workflow and using blank as a parent.

1. Overwrite `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_module.less` in to your theme.
2. Add your changes
3. Compile how you normally would, if you aren't sure how then run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` from the root of your Magento installation.